# Wrong Wiring for a Condo Thermostat?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

[image: thermostat wiring]

Hi there. Friend's condo has heat mode turned on by building management but when she turns on heat its just blasting cold air even at 24 degrees celsius. She's wondering if the wiring is wrong. She did get AC during the summer. Its a fan coil system and the thermostat is RTH7400. TIA

edit: more pictures added. I think its because there's an orange cable not wired properly

[image]

Comment: Is this a new problem (so something's changed), or is this the first time your friend has lived here for a winter and it's possibly never worked right?

Comment: She did move in in April. So this is her first time trying the heat

Comment: Call building management to have them investigate. Odds are good that in a condo, she wouldn't be allowed to do much to the HVAC system on her own anyway.

Comment: Has the building turned on the heat?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Building heat was turned on yesterday.
She has taken more photos as someone suggested to take the panel off. https://imgur.com/4d9SvCt

Are we safe to assume, the orange wire should be slotted in? TIA

Comment: Vote to Reopen. Yes, I'd think that not having the orange wire connected may be part of the problem (don't know a lot about HVAC wiring). However, this may still be an issue for maintenance to resolve not the tenant. Simply to protect her from any claims by the landlord that she's done something that's broken things, if nothing else. Maybe send them the pic of the wire not connected to the wiring block. Of course, if you send them that pic, they know she's been in there and might blame her anyway...

Comment: @FreeMan good points thanks so much. The condo management said they can send someone but she would still have to pay the fee hence the hesitation on her side if its something we can fix. I'll try connecting and if it works its a good sign. If not I'll unplug and call for real help then.
Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the orange that's obviously out, the black and white isn't looking that great:

[image]

[image]

That's more bare wires exposed than I'm comfortable with. These connectors are relatively simple, so if you know how to reconnect the orange, I would just check each one and make sure that it is seated properly and secured.

Make sure you do this carefully and not short anything.

Comment: Thank you!
I've helped her out with all the wire suggestion and seated everything so no copper is showing and we do feel the heat blowing now.
Money saved for her. She's very appreciative. Thanks again everyone!